# How to get id of a div from safeHtml?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I have one html saved in database, which i get from API call.
this is the response

ex.

```
htmlText = <div class="dragBlock"> 
                <div id="Name">Test</div>
                 <div id="Age">23</div>
           </div>
```

In view i am showing this as

```
<div class="preview">
    <div [innerHtml] = "htmlText | safeHtml"> </div>
 </div>
```

this works fine, but i want to change inner Html of id Name and Age

In ts file I am doing this

```
document.getElementById('Name').innerHtml = 'UserName';
```

but this is not working, Can we do this in Angular? If yes how?

Comment: I would suggest you to pass JSON data from the API (if possible) and render the HTML in the client-side after you manipulate it, based on your needs.

Comment: this is just a sample example, actual HTML is big.. I am designing it from one component, the same design I want to use in another component with different data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need use it like this:

```
document.getElementById('Name').innerHTML = 'UserName';
```

See this Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbxeon?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: this works in normal scenario not when it is <div [innerHtml] = "htmlText | safeHtml"> </div>. Please read the question

Comment: check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-safehtml-emycf8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts, it is working for me.

Comment: Cool it works.. I need to change my code structure. Thanks

Comment: Great, you would like to accept/upvote if it worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pipe to manipulate the HTML.

```
  import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
  import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
  
  @Pipe({
    name: 'modify'
  })
  export class ModifyPipe implements PipeTransform {
  
    constructor(private _domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}
  
    transform(html: string, args?: any): any {
      return this._domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.modify(html));
    }
  
    private modify(html: string): string {
      // Do your manipulation here by replacing with regex
      return string;
    }
  
  }


  <p [innerHTML]="htmlText | modify"></p>
```